How to create a parameterized query for pandas with a dynamic table name that avoids SQL injection?
I am using SQL Server, pandas, and pyodbc.
I am trying to make a function that can take a column name, table name, another column name (for a GUID-type column), and a GUID value and make an SQL call like SELECT columnName1 FROM tableName WHERE columnName2 = guidValue.
This function was working just fine when I wasn't worrying about SQL injection and I was just manually sticking square brackets where needed:
def get_sql_entity_set_data(entity_set_name, filter_expression=None, query_params='*'):
    connString = get_connection_string()
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
    query = "SELECT " + query_params + " FROM [" + entity_set_name + "]"

    if filter_expression:
        query += " WHERE " + filter_expression

    logger.debug(f'Attempting the following SQL command: {query}.')
    retValue = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    returnCount = len(retValue.index)

    if returnCount == 0:
        logger.warning('Fetch failed: no data retrieved.')
    else:
        logger.info(f'{returnCount} row(s) retrieved.')

    return retValue

(When I was doing it that way, I would pass the full WHERE clause as a parameter - e.g., "[Name] = 'Bob Smith'".)
But now I am trying to protect against SQL injection and having a devil of a time. Nothing I try works. I have learned that you can't parameterize table names. I also learned that you can't pass the asterisk '*' as a parameter - e.g., SELECT ? FROM..., so my function got a lot uglier with if logic to handle whether the SELECT column name was specified in the parameters or it was just defaulted to '*'.
I was under the impression that I would be able to work around the can't-parameterize-table-name issue by making a prepared statement using EXEC, so I have tried various prepared statements build up from this basic idea (just trying to come up with a simplified example off the top of my head)...
DECLARE @table nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @table = ?;
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM @table';
EXEC @query;

...but that didn't work.
At this point, I have given up on that approach and just put the table name right in the connection string as before. The only thing I'm doing is using another function to wrap it in square brackets. This is the state of my code right now, and it's still not working (no error, it just returns 0 results, even though I have confirmed on SSMS that the parameters I'm feeding it should get 1 result):
def get_data_with_guid_filter(entity_set_name, filter_col, filter_val):
    connString = get_connection_string()
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
    logger.debug(f'Attempting to fetch all data from {entity_set_name} where {filter_col} = {filter_val}.')
    entity_set_name = paramaterize(entity_set_name, "sysid")
    filter_col = paramaterize(filter_col, "sysid")
    filter_val = paramaterize(filter_val, "guid")
    params_tuple = (filter_col,) + (filter_val,)
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {entity_set_name} WHERE ? = ?"

    retValue = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params_tuple)

    returnCount = len(retValue.index)

    if returnCount == 0:
        logger.warning('Fetch failed: no data retrieved.')
    else:
        logger.info(f'{returnCount} row(s) retrieved.')

    return retValue

def paramaterize(param, param_type):
    if param_type == "guid":
        return f"(SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{param}'))"
    elif param_type == "string":
        return f"'{param}'"
    elif param_type == "sysid":
        return f"[{param}]"
    else:
        return param

Let's say the parameters are 'mytable', 'ID', and '123456' [not literally - just pretend that's a real GUID]. I can go into SSMS right now, enter SELECT * FROM [mytable] WHERE [ID] = (SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '123456')), and get 1 result. But in Python, I get zero results and no error.
What's extra weird is I still get 0 results and no error even if I do either of these:

change filter_val = paramaterize(filter_val, "guid") to filter_val = paramaterize(filter_val, "string") (this is weird to me, because when I was trying the EXEC approach, I got an error that I understood to mean I could not filter a GUID column by an nvarchar value in a prepared statement!)
remove the outer brackets from the value that gets returned by filter_val = paramaterize(filter_val, "guid"), even though SSMS seems to require those brackets


SQL is not intended to be used in a generic way as you are trying to do, its a statically typed language and as such the best way to use it is with specific calls to specific tables, not generic calls.

You can only parametrize some things, like variables inside expression and a couple of backup / restore parameters, but not table or column names. I think it's a waste of time to protect anything, because you won't be able to do this with the above style of code. Better bin the whole thing and use specific sql for specific entities

This question is similar to: pyodbc - How to perform a select statement using a variable for a parameter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you find yourself needing to parametrised objects then you've gone wrong in your design phase. That might be at the database level, or it light be in the application. Based on the above, it seems the latter.

From the pandas read_sql docs, you can parameterize via the params attribute, but the exact format is db connector dependent. I think you could simplify the question by using params, reviewing what is not doable with your backend, and focusing just on that issue.

Fairly sure this return f"(SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{param}'))" will not work, you're trying to pass an expression as a parameter which you can't do. However you don't need to. You can (and should) pass a GUID as a string so long as its formatted correctly.

The comments and a bit more digging helped guide me to the solution I was looking for. This allows me to have a function that dynamically makes an SQL call given table name, column name, and GUID parameters while also (AFAIK) providing security against SQL injection:
def get_sql_entity_set_data(entity_set_name, filter_col=None, filter_val=None):
    connString = get_connection_string()
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
    entity_set_name = paramaterize(entity_set_name)

    if filter_col is not None and filter_val is not None:
        filter_col = paramaterize(filter_col)

        query = f"""
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DECLARE @table nvarchar(128) = {entity_set_name};
            DECLARE @whereColumn nvarchar(128) = {filter_col};
            DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@whereColumn) + ' = ' + ?;
            EXEC sp_executesql @query
        """

        logger.debug(f'Attempting the following SQL command: {query}.')
        retValue = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=(paramaterize(filter_val),))
    else:
        query = f"""
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DECLARE @table nvarchar(128) = {entity_set_name};
            DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table);
            EXEC sp_executesql @query
        """

        logger.debug(f'Attempting the following SQL command: {query}.')
        retValue = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    returnCount = len(retValue.index)

    if returnCount == 0:
        logger.warning('Fetch failed: no data retrieved.')
    else:
        logger.info(f'{returnCount} row(s) retrieved.')

    return retValue

def paramaterize(param):
    return f"'{param}'"

Note: I learned that I couldn't use a ? for a column name either (just like I couldn't use one for a table name).

With current versions of pandas (e.g., version 2.x), users following the other answer may notice this warning:

UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

That is, if you are using pandas with a database other than SQLite you should be using SQLAlchemy.
The corresponding function using SQLAlchemy would be:
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

def get_sql_entity_set_data(entity_set_name, filter_col=None, filter_val=None):
    connString = get_connection_string()
    engine = sa.create_engine(
        sa.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query=dict(odbc_connect=connString))
    )
    tbl = sa.Table(entity_set_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
    query = sa.select(tbl)
    if filter_col is not None and filter_val is not None:
        query = query.where(tbl.c[filter_col] == filter_val)
    retValue = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)

    returnCount = len(retValue.index)

    if returnCount == 0:
        logger.warning('Fetch failed: no data retrieved.')
    else:
        logger.info(f'{returnCount} row(s) retrieved.')

    return retValue

